# Quickfix or Quickfix/n, through which message type are custom U1, U2,....,Un messages identified?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I cannot find anywhere how to manage custom U-type messages. I use MessageCracker and need to understand the corresponding OnMessage method signature. For example my broker sends custom U1,U5, U2 messages, how can I capture those incoming messages inside a OnMessage method? I understand that Tag35 identifies those but if I cannot capture them through OnMessage then MessageCracker becomes kind of useless and I need to identify each message by Tag35 within FromApp or FromAdmin. Any suggestion how to handle those kind of custom U-types?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, custom messages.  Fun stuff.

1. You need to add your counterparty's customizations to the DataDictionary xml file.  Choose the appropriate FIXnn.xml file for your FIX version.

   - See here: http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/custom-fields-groups-and-messages
2. Then, because you are adding custom messages, you'll want to regenerate the QF/n source and rebuild the library so you can get classes for your new messages.

   - Instructions for rebuilding are here: https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn
   - You'll need to install Ruby.  This annoys some people, but we haven't found any more-windows-oriented code-generator that we don't hate.  Sorry in advance.
   - (If you were just adding fields to existing messages, you could probably get away with not rebuilding.  But you're adding messages, so you pretty much have to regenerate/rebuild.)

To Windows developers, it may seem annoying that rebuilding the library is required, but it really is the norm for all the QF engines.  FIX is just too fudgey a protocol for a single build to satisfy everyone, because it seems that every counterparty likes to screw with the message definitions.

Comment: so you are saying that I need to generate a new library for each broker I want to support and for each future QF update I want to take advantage of I would have to run through the same procedure? That sounds incredibly cumbersome but if thats the only way to do it currently...why not using the code generator to generate a segregated code library. In that way the core library remains untouched and the added message code can just be referenced.

Comment: by the way, I am confused how complicated it is to, for example, add symbols to a market data request. Given this is a "wrapping" application that creates string messages anyway, why not for example taking advantage of .Net collections (such as List<string>) and have the user simply add symbols in that way and the parsing is done under the hood?

Comment: ...in reference to my first comment, in the case of my suggestion the library would potentially even be QF version agnostic. Just because you guys move to version 1.5 most likely does not change a thing about the custom message code. And in the rare event that you change your structure so much that the custom generated code loses compatibility then the code would break at compile time. Not a bad thing I feel...just my 2 cents...

Comment: QF/n is still a fairly young project.  Our first priority was making the interface similar to the other QuickFIX ports so that it would remain familiar to developers.  Certainly there are things we can do to take advantage of .Net features, but no one's proposed them.

Comment: To your other point, we do have issues open to split up the features into sub-libraries. What you propose is not entirely out of the question.

Comment: Grant, thanks for your input. However, I admit I am still slightly stuck with your idea of mixing datadictionary xml files. What would I do if I have conflicting messages because I want to support 2 brokers who require different tags in MarketDataRequest ("V") to be populated? Would I add both xml entries from both broker dataDictionaries to the same FIX44 version xml DD (of course given they both target 4.4)? How would the code be created? Same method but different parameter signature? Could you pls elaborate on that?

Comment: This is in no way a criticism but just feedback: I start to feel that it might be much easier to create a non type safe message each time by just populating the tags as required by the broker spec. This is a one-time exercise and it will not be exposed to the end-user nor does it change. The inconvenience I see with all those type  -safe message methods is that most always tags have to be manually added/manipulated anyway. But I admit I have no re-built the library with the new xml file. Maybe I am missing some concept here...

Comment: Grant, can I please confirm that I need Ruby? Why is that? I thought calling the batch file runs the build process?

Comment: Grant, I tried it but adding custom messages, or for that matter replacing the complete FIX44.xml file with a fully functional xml data dictionary from the broker does not generate any code that encompasses the custom message types in question.

Comment: The generator is a Ruby script.  generate.bat does the code generation.  build.bat compiles it.

Comment: I tried with the custom broker xml data dictionary. But after re-building none of the custom messages are available. The build showed there were no errors or warnings.

Comment: I was able to generate the code after installing Ruby 1.9.3 and the Nokugiri gem.

Comment: I've never used QuickFIX/N, but for QuickFIX and QuickFIX/J, you do NOT need to generate a library for every data dictionary variant. The data dictionary is required for parsing (e.g., repeated groups) and for validation. The code generation is a convenience and type safety. There are non type-safe APIs (at least in the other QuickFIX implementations) to build messages and access message fields. It's also easy to write your own MessageCracker (or equivalent) implementation.

Comment: It's not that I don't like Ruby in general, but I've always felt that the Ruby code generation in QuickFIX was a bad decision. For QuickFIX/N, why not use T4 text templates? I'm guessing it's because the Ruby generator was already there from QuickFIX.

Comment: Even in the other QFs, you should regenerate if you're *sending* custom *messages*.  Which Mr. Wolf is doing.

Comment: Again, that may be necessary in the QuickFIX/N implementation, but at least in QuickFIX/J it's not necessary. The message formatter uses the internal FieldMap and Group collection to generate messages. The formatter knows nothing about custom versus standard messages. It just formats the tag/values in those data structures. I'd need to double-check but I believe it's the same with QuickFIX C++.